# NetworkX: list individual and unique path lengths in a graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

[Image of the graph and what I would like to generate if this is helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYaG3.png)
.

Hello!

I am currently working on a problem where I am exploring the connectivity of a Graph (nx.Graph)

Is there a simple function or tool that will allow me to compile a list of lengths, where a length is defined as:

> the total number of nodes that share some degree of seperation ... or total number of nodes on a path,including branches

If this could read this into either a list where entries are lengths or a dictionary where key,value =length,#number of instances of that length, that would be awesome

Excited for the help!

Comment: would any of [these](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/centrality.html) work?